# Excel: 299 blank pages in page break preview

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, printing

I have an Excel document in which only cells A1:L50 have data in them. In the Page Break Preview, the blue lines enclose A1:L68. In effect, the print area is page 1 plus a small portion of page 2.

I deleted rows 51 to 68. Now, the print area was A1:L1560, totaling 30 pages.

I selected A1:15600 and deleted the cells. Now, the print area was A1:L15600, totaling 300 pages.

Is this document corrupted?

Comment: Tried your steps and I didn't have this problem, did you try to copy data to a new Workbook and check the result?

Comment: I have problem with this particular worksheet only. That's why I suspect the file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The likeliest cause of this progression is perhaps in the print manager choices.

In particular, if the choice of what, in the selected range to print, is "Print Selection", AND you highlighted the areas to delete, then deleted them, but did NOT unhighlight the area selected for deleting (AND do not have a preset print range ("Set Print Area")), then print manager would be taking your highlighted area ("Selection" in "Print Selection") and planning to print it.

Given the progression of enlarged print areas indicated after deleting precisely the same areas, this really seems a good bet.

Comment: It was not in the "Print Selection" mode and nothing was selected. I had cleared and cleared and cleared the print area to no avail. I think I'll just do what Lee suggested: copy data to a new workbook and forget about this one.